# Searching a string of consecutive characters in a binary bar code

Tags: c++, strings, search

I am writing a program that will take a binary bar code and convert it to a zip-code. I need to validate the bar code. A valid binary bar code contains no more and no less than two 1s in any position per five digits. This is what I have for the validation part so far and would like simplify this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;//number of characters to test in a set
    string bar = "100101010010001";

    string tempstring;
    int count = 0;
    while (count < bar.length())
    {
        int test = 0;
        tempstring = bar.substr(count, SIZE);//split bar string into next five characters

        for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
        {
            if (tempstring[index] == '1')
            {
                ++test;
            }
        }

        if (test != 2)
        {
            cout << "Invalid bar code!\n";
            exit(1);
        }

        count += 5;
    }

    cout << "Valid bar code!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without creating a temp string,
simply by using `bar[count + index]` instead of `tempstring[index]`.
Also, the `while` loop would be more natural as a `for` loop.
Like this, with some other improvements:

```
for (int count = 0; count < bar.length(); count += 5)
{
    int ones = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
    {
        if (bar[count + index] == '1')
        {
            ++ones;
        }
    }

    if (ones != 2)
    {
        cout << "Invalid bar code!\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- The constant `SIZE` and its comment don't quite seem consistent.  A name such as size would correspond to an actual size of, say, a structure.  But with such a comment, it doesn't seem to be for that.  Consider renaming the constant to something more accurate.
- `bar` should be `const` since it's not modified.
- `test` seems like an ambiguous name for an integer variable.  It sounds more like a Boolean test flag, but that's not the case here.  Consider renaming it to something more accurate.
- Since `tempstring` is only used within the `while` loop, it can just be initialized there.  It doesn't need to be declared before it.
- You shouldn't mismatch integer types when doing comparisons:

  > ```
  > while (count < bar.length())
  > ```

  Since `length()` returns an `std::size_t`, which is an unsigned type, have `count` be of type `std::size_t` as well.  If you had compiler warnings up, then this should've been reported.
- This may be a small nit-pick, but you can just `return 1` instead of calling `exit()` in `main()`.

Answer (score 2):

- Last substring may contain less than `SIZE` characters. I suppose you want to reject such strings too.
- `string.substr()` creates a new object. It doesn't matter in a toy program; in general I recommend to avoid creating temporary objects.
- You may want to consider `std::accumulate()` instead of spelling out the counting loop.